# cppzmq: Is it possible to get a global context without creating one as a global variable?

Tags: c++, zeromq

My usecases usually involve only one global context. AFAIK, pyzmq has an API `zmq.Context.instance()` to get the global singleton, but I couldn't find an equivalent `cppzmq` API.

Is it possible to have access to a global context without having to create it explicitly and track it?

Comment: Looks like you will have to create your own singleton and manage its lifetime.

Comment: Singletons are considered antipatterns, which is a reason for not using them, let alone providing them as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q** : *Is it possible to have access to a global context without having to **create it** explicitly and **track it**?*

No, at least not without a principal re-design work of the current `cppzmq`

### REASON :

PyZMQ recently ***started* not to be the same** as an ordinary python language binding for working with a published common ZeroMQ API.

> **More Than Just Bindings**
>
> PyZMQ is ostensibly the Python bindings for ØMQ, but the project, following Python’s ‘batteries included’ philosophy, provides more than just Python methods and objects for calling into the ØMQ C++ library.
>   The Core as Bindings
>
> PyZMQ is currently broken up into four subpackages. First, is the <kbd>`Core`</kbd>. **`zmq.core`** contains the actual bindings for ZeroMQ, and no extended functionality beyond the very basic. The core modules are split, such that each basic ZeroMQ object (or function, if no object is associated) is a separate module, e.g. **`zmq.core.context`** contains the **`Context`** object, `zmq.core.poll` contains a `Poller` object, as well as the `select()` function, etc. ZMQ constants are, for convenience, all kept together in `zmq.core.constants`.
>
> There are two reasons for breaking the core into submodules: recompilation and derivative projects. The monolithic PyZMQ became quite tedious to have to recompile everything for a small change to a single object. With separate files, that’s no longer necessary. The second reason has to do with Cython. PyZMQ is written in Cython, a tool for efficiently writing C-extensions for Python. By separating out our objects into individual pyx files, each with their declarations in a pxd header, other projects can write extensions in Cython and call directly to ZeroMQ at the C-level without the penalty of going through our Python objects.
>
> **Thread Safety**
>
> In ØMQ, Contexts are threadsafe objects, but Sockets are not. It is safe to use a single `Context` (e.g. via **`zmq.Context.instance()`**) in your entire multithreaded application, but you should create sockets on a per-thread basis. If you share sockets across threads, you are likely to encounter ***uncatchable*** c-level ***crashes of your application*** unless you use judicious application of **`threading.Lock`**, but ***this approach is not recommended.***

Hard working ZeroMQ geeks have already noticed, that the original ZeroMQ API ( since as early days as v2.1.11+ ) has other pieces of advice:

1) app **must** explicitly create at least one `Context`-instance ( and terminate it later )

2) `Context`-instance(s) is(are) free to be shared across the threads **without** any locking required on the `Context`-service caller-side

3) Thread safety is granted even for passing (not migrating) `Socket`-instance(s) to a newly created thread ( i.e. maintained by a thread not owned "foreign"-`Context` ), from which the PyZMQ documentation explicitly warns and distracts users from ever doing.

Comment: Again. Great summary and resources. Thank you!